# Floating point arithmetic unstability

Tags: math, floating-point, computer-science, precision

For a function like f(x) = sqrt(1+x) - sqrt(1-x), we get unwanted results for a certain range of x values. However, we can rewrite the equation in a piecewise manner to use the original equation in certain cases and the new equation in others.

How do I go about figuring out the range of x values and finding an alternate expression for questions like these? (From researching online I found that you don't want functions to essentially "cancel out" for certain values, but is that all we're looking for? For example, in f(x) = e^x - 1, are we ALWAYS just looking around for f(x) = 0?)

Comment: This question is much too broad as written. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Can you provide a range of values of x where f(x) = sqrt(1+x) - sqrt(1-x) gives poor results when evaluated using floating-point arithmetic? Provide an alternative expression for f(x) for these values of x so that the "cancellation error" does not occur.

Comment: @Brainpower2049: small `x` are problematic. For example, `f(1e-16)` gives `1.1102230246251565e-16`, while `f(1e-17)` gives `0.0`. An expressions that's mathematically but not numerically equivalent is `2*x / (sqrt(1+x) + sqrt(1-x))`. This gives good results numerically across the entire domain `[-1.0, 1.0]`.

Comment: Note that, in double precision, 1.0+1e-17 == 1.0 -1e-17 == 1.0

Comment: `1+x` or `1-x` will fall to `1` for `x` below a certain value due to limited numbers representation, ruining your calculus. Knowing the `x` problematic range I'll go with Taylor series. In your case, `x=0` like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516863/finding-taylors-expansion-for-fx-sqrt1-x-sqrt-1-x). Note that you stop adding members when they have no effect on result, i.e. no more precision is achieved.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there aren't any golden bullets here: the usual way is a lot of experimentation and finicky error analysis. Some tools that are useful:

- arbitrary precision arithmetic libraries, such as MPFR, to compute expressions using higher-precision and compare the result against normal precision. I like using Julia for this, as it provides a `BigFloat` type which supports generic math operators and functions.
- interval arithmetic: provides guaranteed bounds on the error (so unstable computations will blow-up). The only package I have personal experience with is [ValidatedNumerics.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIntervals/ValidatedNumerics.jl) (see the [examples](https://github.com/JuliaIntervals/ValidatedNumerics.jl/tree/master/examples)).
- [herbie](https://herbie.uwplse.org/) uses some fancy tricks to automatically rewrite numerical expressions to be more stable. I have no personal experience with it, but it does look cool. (By coincidence, the example they have on their homepage is pretty close to yours)

Comment: I think herbie needs to be a lot more sophisticated (or less buggy) before it's useful. Entering the OP's expression gave me back `1/8 x^3/  + (7/128 x^5  + x)`, without any indication of what domain this expression might be useful in.

Comment: That's odd: I just tried it out the little web app thingy, and it gave the answer you suggested in the question to the question: `(x+x) / (sqrt(1+x) + sqrt(1-x))`.

Comment: Hmm, that _is_ odd. I still get the same result as before (the Taylor series expansion around 0). It looks like there's some random input to the algorithms, though; maybe that explains it.